# Where are the I18n.t link and reference paths?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I am looking through a starter package that has the following haml code:

```
%li= link_to I18n.t('admin.link'), rails_admin_path
```

I am trying to locate where the `home_user_path` is. In [Rails Internationalization (I18n) API](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html), I found `admin.link` and I understand this. However I don't understand where `rails_admin_path` is located or referenced and where it is defined. I don't see it in the routes or in a controller or inherited class. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two questions here:

1) where are the internationalized values stored: answer `config/locales/<locale-code>.yml`

and

2) how do path helpers work

Path helpers can (and probably should typically) be created automatically when you define a new  set of routes in `config/routes.rb`.  These days (Rails 3+) it can be a little sneaky, because if your model is called "Toys", then `routes.rb` might just need a line `resources :toys`.  From this a whole set of paths, URLs and other goodies are generated and available whenever you want a URL or path.  You can see what's available by running `rake routes` from your application root folder.

Lots of good information on [routing with rails here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: It just clicked and makes sense to me now. Thank you!